# Working with Laravel routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I built my application using Angularjs on the frontend and Laravel 5 at the backend, however my main issue now is routing, when the page is loaded initially I set it to return my angular.php view I even added some code to catch all routes and return that view for me.

This does not work in all cases:

**routes.php**

```
Route::any('{url?}', function($url) {
    return view('angular');
})->where(['url' => '[-a-z0-9/]+']);
```

Example of a URL **that works** with this is:

```
http://localhost:8000/tickets/events/catgeories/
```

Example of a URL that **does not work** with this is:

```
http://localhost:8000/tickets/events/Musical/Some-event-name
```

By "not working" I mean Laravel throws a **NotFoundHttpException**. What I am thinking right now is the above route can't go past three levels/parameters as in **/level-1/level-2/level-3**.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you should include uppercases in your route by using a-Z instead of a-z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because second URL has uppercase characters?

Comment: Wow you know i actually thought that didn't matter in urls, so i didn't even bother, fixed it now, thanks. :)

Comment: Yes it actually doesnt matter, but as you are doing special regexp without uppercase it fails.